# How set .bat file to C++

Tags: c++

Can any one help ,i have create bat file now i want convert to C++

In my .bat file i need to create another file call name.bat, so right now i want use C++ to execute all this command.

Here my Sample:

```
set /p CID=Curr_ID= 

set /p CIP=Curr_IP= 

set /p CIS=Curr_SUBNET= 

echo Curr_POrt must convert HEx to Dec

set /p CIPR=Curr_PORT= 

set /p NID=New_ID= 

echo cd\ >> if.bat

echo cls >> if.bat

echo if exist del.bat goto :label1 >> if.bat

echo :label1 >> if.bat

echo cd\ >> if.bat

echo c: >> if.bat

echo cls >> if.bat

echo @echo off

echo echo Setup Done !!! >> if.bat

echo pause >> if.bat

echo del del.bat >> if.bat

echo del name.bat >> if.bat

echo del if.bat >> if.bat

echo exit >> if.bat

echo del name.bat >> del.bat

echo cd rdsconfig >> name.bat

echo rdsconfig.exe /CURR_ID=%CID% /CURR_IP=%CIP% /CURR_SUBNET=%CIS% /CURR_PORT=%CIPR% /NEW_ID=%NID% /NEW_IP=192.168.2.%NID% /NEW_SUBNET=255.255.255.0 /NEW_PORT=33536 >> name.bat

START name.BAT
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert this script to C++?

Comment: The batch file has errors, so yes, it's a good idea to translate this to some other language. I'd use Python. Or JScript.

Comment: Hi computergeek6  im still new in C++ so now i want to now how to convert from batch file to C++ . i always use batch file :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can efficiently auto-convert from batch to C++, but you could just run each of the commands in the batch file sequentially with system(). Here's an example:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    system("cls");
    return 0;
}
```

That would clear the screen. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way that I know of to convert BATCH in to C++ automatically, however if you just want an EXE, there are plenty of applications that will do that for you, such as [BatToEXE](http://www.battoexe.com/)

Comment: ok Thanks but if some one can show me how to create using C++ :)